# --move option of jets3t synchronize not moving S3 file

Tags: amazon-s3, jets3t

I was trying to use --move option with jets3t Synchronize tool to move files from S3 folder to local directory with below command.

```
./synchronize.sh DOWN --move mybucket/folder/ /mylocal-directory/
```

I was expecting after execution of this command, files in S3 folder would be removed, however files remain in S3 as if no --move option was supplied. Moreover the command reports it has moved files:

```
New files: 2, Updated: 0, Reverted: 0, Deleted: 0, Unchanged: 0, Moved: 2
```

However in reality it did not.

My jets3t version is 0.8.1a

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

It has a command `aws s3 mv` that should support your need.

See: [AWS CLI mv documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, however installing aws in our server is not an option. I tried upgrading jets3t version to 0.9.2. Now the --move option works fine.